How to prevent jumping to editing line on Espressif IDE (Eclipse) on clone tabs?
I like write code with two tabs (left and right in one window). Sometimes I need to open one file in both tabs (Eclipse can do it by the cloning tab mechanism). But Eclipse jump to editing line on cloned tab when I change line in original tab, i.e. if I open "main.c" on left panel, clone it (so now I have two tabs with main.c on left panel), next I move cloned tab to right and have one file opened in two edit panels. But if I change lines on left panel, right panel scroll to this lines to. I do not need this behavior. I want to see and edit one file in different places opened in different panels without sync scrolling (in both direction). What's interesting - whis works in one direction only, i.e. there is always scrolling on right tab if I edit lines in left panel, but changing lines on right do not cause of scrolling on left tab. I do not find where tunning this behavior on preferences.
I try to playing with cloning right tab to left panel, I try to open clone tabs twise and work with they, but I did not find solution for my problem. And I did not find discussion of this or similar  problems.

I cannot reproduce this with the Text Editor in Eclipse 2024-09. Can you reproduce this with the Text Editor or only in a specific editor? If so, which one?

Indeed, this is not a problem with Eclipse, but with Espressif IDE.
The behaviour I have described does not work in Eclipse 2024-09 R, and the problem does not occur when creating a C/C++ project in Espressif IDE.
The behaviour is consistently reproduced only when creating an Espressif IDF Project.
I have marked and formatted the question incorrectly.
I think that the reason is in one of the code analysis mechanisms, but I do not understand which one and how to find it.

I don't know the Espressif IDE. If you do not get an answer here, you might ask directly at the Espressif IDE project: https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin
